# Why isn't my timer working?

Tags: java, timer

```
public class TimerProgram extends JFrame {
    public TimerProgram(){

       int  DELAY=1000;
       Timer t = new Timer(DELAY,new TimerListener());
          t.start();

    }
      class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Hello");

          }
        }     

      public static void main(String[]args){
          new TimerProgram();
      }
}
```

I am trying to make a timer that outputs every second the word hello, but it seems that when I type as the DELAY value 1000 , it outputs hello once and then it terminates. What am I doing wrong ? All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM exited before the Timer fired.

Try:

```
t.setInitialDelay(0);
t.start();
```

to see the difference.

Or a better approach is to execute the code on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). All GUI code should execute on the EDT. By using SwingUtitities.invokeLater() you ensure the EDT has been created when your code executes:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
          new TimerProgram();
    }
});
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT.

Comment: i tried it but the only difference now is that it outputs two hellos instead of one

Comment: @monkey6991, works ok on Windows 7 using JDK 7, however, my second suggestion is the better answer and should be used.

Comment: I am running on Win 8 and it doesn't work for me, as for the second option you gave me , I am a beginner java programmer and I don't have that much knowledge on timer classes

Comment: @monkey6991, It doesn't have anything to do with the TImer. It has to do with the Threads. Read the tutorial link for more information.

Comment: @monkey6991, check out the API for the `Frame.dispose()` method. In the method description you will find a link on `AWT Threading Issues`, which will explain more about the different Threads in the JVM and why sometimes is shuts down and other times it doesn't.